# Google+ button broke tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-plus-one

I have created my [Portfolio](http://portfolio.yanavichus.info) and put there a Google+ button. The page is still unstyled and the broken tooltip is slowing me down. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a conflicting style in your stylsheet css/style.css that is causing the problem.

If I get rid of that stylesheet ti works as it should.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have disabled all styles and it works!!! But I have already done it before and it did not work but now I have cleaned browser cache and it is all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you go that code but you way want to replace it this : http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: The code in my page is from that url. I have just selected html5 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<div class="g-plusone">
        </div>
```

Try:

```
<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>
```

Comment: What about <div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline"></div> ?